# Филосóфия, но филóсоф

Tags: орфоэпия

По какому правилу, принципу ударение в словах *философия* и *философ* отличается?

Лично для меня, оба звучания – филóсоф и филосóф – приемлемы, в связи с чем вопрос и возник:

*почему, если можно оставить ударение на одном месте  без уродования языка (хотя,  как мне кажется, это все относительно и что сегодня кажется уродливым, завтра вполне может таковым не казаться), оно все-таки переносится?*

Comment: Ударение плавающая штука. То же с *биол**о**гия-би**о**лог, геогр*а*фия-ге**о**граф.*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, но почему так происходит?

Comment: Потому что неудобно его всегда оставлять на одном месте, звучание хорошее от этого тоже будет не в выигрыше.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой,  "неудобно его всегда оставлять на одном месте" вроде как раз удобно, или я о чем-то другом? "звучание хорошее от этого тоже будет не в выигрыше" - вот тут совсем непонятно (для меня филОсоф  и филосОф звучат одинаково), хотя конечно в этом и может быть причина. Но тогда хотелось бы найти источник, в котором говорится, что причина как раз таки в "хорошем звучании", в чем собственно и состоит вопрос.

Comment: Ну хорошо, *ист**о**рия* слово возьмём. Вы предлагаете говорить *ист**о**рический?* Красиво? А *матем**а**тический?*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой в вопросах акцентологии всегда можно найти исключение. Например, имеется куча слов на -ический, в которых ударение падает на третий с конца слог. Тенденция? Определённо, но вот вам: х*и*щнический, со*ю*знический, ж*у*льнический...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, согласен, истОрический звучит ужасно, но ведь вопрос и не о нем. Вопрос о том, что филОсоф звучит так же хорошо (по крайней мере для меня) как филосОф, но почему-то все-таки филОсоф. И вот именно это "почему"  и интересует. Согласен, что так можно договориться до "почему мы так говорим вообще", но опять же, вопрос только к этой паре.

Comment: Не скажу вам именно за это слово... Но [вот](http://netler.ru/articles/filosof.htm) что я нашёл, занимательно. ;)

Comment: Почитал ваши комментарии, вы немного увлеклись, имхо... Конкретный пример (философ) связан с историческим процессом и не подлежит обобщению на другие приведенные участниками дискуссии случаи. Подробнее - в моем ответе.

Comment: @behemothus: вчера, ещё прежде чем написать последний комментарий с цитатой Пушкина, я пытался найти подтверждение, что раньше было как раз *филос**о**ф.* Когда нашёл у Пушкина *фил**о**соф,* подумал, что, возможно, в церковнославянском *филос**о**ф,* потому что вспомнились слова канона Живоносному Источнику, который поют под пятницу Светлой седмицы, казалось, что там именно на последний слог. Однако ударения вчера не нашёл, загуглив, как ни старался. Зато сегодня, поискав в яндексе, всё же [нашёл](https://russportal.ru/index.php?id=liturgical_book.pentecostarion1864_00_106)! См. конец 6 песни

Comment: Цитирую: *...и облича́ется филосо́фовъ че́стность и ри́торовъ красота́.*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, спасибо!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *возможно, в церковнославянском филос**о**ф* - да, но что из этого следует? ЦСЯ нам не указ.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой а вообще-то вы меня вдохновили на то, чтобы дополнить свой ответ еще одним небольшим замечанием. Полагаю, в тему будет

Comment: @behemothus: рад, что вдохновил вас на это дополнение!) Кстати, в английском complex тоже есть два варианта ударения и даже на последний слог чаще произносят, но мне больше нравится на первый. В математике *компл**е**ксный,* конечно, свято — это я не трогаю. ;)

Answer (score 2):

> По какому правилу, принципу ударение в словах философия и философ
> отличается?

Тут нет правил, максимум - некие статистические закономерности, не несущие императивного характера. Вы неверно вопрос ставите.

> почему, если можно оставить ударение на одном месте

Вопросы начинающиеся с "почему" как правило бессодержательны. Потому что язык так устроен и не подчиняется вашим взглядам на то, каким он должен быть.
В вашем случае (как и во многих других подобных) - нет каких-то причинно следственных связей, которые единственно и могли бы корректно ответить на вопрос "почему".
Максимум, на что можно ответить - так это на вопрос, что позволяет языку допускать переход ударения, другими словами - реализовывать принцип его подвижности. Да и то, такой ответ будет не слишком конструктивным. Я имею в виду тот факт, что ударение в русском почти не выполняет смыслоразличительную функцию, а строй речи не предполагает ритмичности. Вообще языков, где ударение строго сидело бы на корне не так много (условно - немецкий), а таких, чтобы на других морфах - и, понятно, нет вовсе. Зато есть масса примеров языков, где ударение падает на фиксированный слог от начала или конца (финский, венгерский, польский, английский - условно, скандинавские, французский).  Но это отдельный разговор...

> если можно оставить ударение на одном месте

В каком смысле "можно"? Нельзя оставить. Это будет нарушением языковых норм.

Возьмём корень **"ключ"**. Есть слово "кл**ю**чник" - с ударением на корне. Милый вашему сердцу пример.
Но есть и слово "включ**и**ть". У него ударение строго на суффиксе, попытка перенести его на корень приводит к нарушению норм: "вкл**ю**чит" - ненормативно, хотя, по мнению многих (ошибочному!), язык "не уродует".
Дальше - больше. Есть глагол "в**ы**ключить". Приставка ВЫ всегда перетягивает ударение на себя, во всех формах. Ну не может она без этого жить. Надо продолжать?

Надеюсь, понятно, насколько бессодержательным в этой ситуации была бы попытка закрепить ударение на корне?

> Филосóфия, но филóсоф

А исторически-то как раз - филосóф.
https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/9673/%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84
(Горбачевич)

Язык ушел от этой нормы, уподоблявшей русское произношение языку-источнику (греческому). Видимо, по мере усвоения языком заимствования оно все более тяготеет к милому русскому слуху ударению на предпоследний слог. Искать смысла тут бесполезно.

Полагаю, что у автора вопроса сработала, если можно так выразиться, историческая языковая память - поэтому вариант "филос**о**ф" и не кажется ему "ужасным".

> возможно, в церковнославянском филос**о**ф

(Артём Луговой)

Ну да. Но тут важнее не сам факт ударения в ЦСЯ, а то, что слово заимствовано. А это приводит иногда к неожиданным (на первый взгляд) результатам.
Так, слово или несколько слов, трактуемые - не всегда справедливо - однокоренными, на самом деле заимствованы в язык разными путями. Это тоже сказывается на месте ударения. В отношении "философа" подозреваю, что он мог быть позаимствован напрямую из греческого (или через ЦСЯ), а вот "философия" явно предварительно прошла обкатку латынью/французским.  Поведение ударения в этом случае непредсказуемо.

Для примера. Слово **"комплексный"** очевидно имеет ударение на первый слог. Для всех, но не для математиков. В математике нормативным считается компл**е**ксный. Да, это термин, но ведь по сути это одно и то же слово, с близким, едва ли не эквивалентным значением. Но слово в общий язык пришло из английского, а в математику - из французского.
Аналогично - **"мизер"** в быту и у картежников имеет разное ударение (карточная терминология, как и математическая, в основе имеет французские корни).

Вот вам еще одна причина подвижности ударения в русском.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Уточните, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понял, что ответом на вопрос
_что позволяет языку допускать переход ударения, другими словами - реализовывать принцип его подвижности_ является предложение  _ударение в русском почти не выполняет смыслоразличительную функцию, а строй речи не предполагает ритмичности_?

Comment: _Надеюсь, понятно, насколько бессодержательным в этой ситуации была бы попытка закрепить ударение на корне_ -- все дело в норме, которая следует из  тяготения русского слуха к ударению на последний слог, верно?

Comment: @RussianIvan *все дело в норме, которая следует из тяготения русского слуха* - Да нет такой нормы. Всё дело в том, что язык не подчиняется вашим представлениям о том, каким он должен быть.

Comment: @RussianIvan правильно ли я понял - вы правильно поняли. Смещение ударения не противоречит языковому строю, напротив, является одним из дополнительных средств передачи смысла. Но я предупредил, что это лишь частичный ответ, полный был бы совершенно неподъемным для здешнего уровня. Да и есть ли он, полный ответ?! Так язык устроен - вот единственный исчерпывающий ответ на все подобные вопросы.

Comment: Вы не против, если я там, где ко мне обращаетесь в ответе, напишу просто *Артёму Луговому?*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Не против. Можете вообще обращение удалить, коли вы уже прочитали. ))) Выбранная мной форма диктуется движком - она (и только она) активизирует мессидж на вашей страничке. В противном случае сообщение может не дойти.

Comment: Да ладно, пусть останется) Мне кажется, что после обращения с собачкой именно в ответе не приходит уведомления. Мне тогда пришло уведомление от комментария, а от ответа нет.